# Problem Regarding Proof by Induction and/or Contradiction

Tags: problem-solving, word-problem

There is a competition involving sixteen people, with each person having 1 round against every other person. If a person wins a round, they get one point. The loser gets zero points, and if it is a draw, both people get half a point. At the end of the rounds, every person ended up with a different total number of points. Prove that there is a person who won more rounds than he had draws using proof by induction or proof by contradiction.

From this problem, I simply deduced that nobody has to draw for everyone to get a different total number of points. Hence, person 1 could get zero points (he lost every round), person 2 could get one point (he won one round but lost every other one), person 3 could get two points (he won two rounds but lost every other one) and so on... However, I think I'm interpreting this question incorrectly as I used neither of the proofs and the question could not possibly be that simple... Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: This looks like a PHP problem.

Comment: I think your solution is consistent with the question (since every person won more rounds than they drew). However, it does not *prove* that there is always a person who won more rounds than they drew.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo I do not think that this abbreviation for "pigeonhole-principle" is very common.

Comment: @Peter It isn't? Well, everyone here in India says PHP.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo I read many exercises with this method, but I never came across this abbreviation.

Comment: @Tohiko then how would it be proven? And if it does involve the pigeonhole-principle, how so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we show that one player must have at least $11.5$ points. Otherwise, the sum of the scores would be at most $$3.5+4+4.5+\cdots +11=116$$ which is too small because the sum must be exactly $120$.

We have $15$ rounds. To get at least $11.5$ with $7$ wins, the player needs $9$ draws and with every win less two additional draws are needed, but this would require at least $16$ rounds.

Hence a player having at least $11.5$ points must at least have won $8$ games, completing the proof.